# How do I write two activities in a app？

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I want write two activities, one is activity, the other is mapactivity, but it can get error message below

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #129: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

PS：
I've written an app about photo upload, and if I want to add GPS functionality at each photo will be uploaded longitude and latitude as a parameter passed to Server, please let me know how to deal, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a map activity inside another activity.

You need to make a Fragment Activity and show the map there

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc)

You can refer to the following video.

Here is a sample code which should help.

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity 
implements OnMapClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap== null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Google Maps not Available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     //   mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
```

Don't forget to get the API Key, and update your manifest correctly.
Make the correct fragment xml as required.

Comment: what is the difference when extending android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity and just FragmentActivity

Comment: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity allows you to run even before API 11 level, thats all. If you are making the app for API 11+ then FragmentActivity is sufficient.

Comment: i used supportMapFragment by extending only FragmentActivity and it works so I was wondering about your solution